# Is MongoDB field ordering behaviour different on _id and other fields?

Tags: mongodb

I have recently encountered a bug in my server and after investigation it happens that MongoDB dictionaries are ordered because of BSON structure.

I thought I understood, but here is a test that I don't understand (mongo 2.6.4) : is it that field ordering matters only for `_id` ?

Test 1 : insert {a: 1, b: 2} and lookup {b: 2, a: 1} -> FOUND

```
> db.d.insert({a: 1, b: 2})
> db.d.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("54c4dfd17e8b0ba11cf1539d"), "a" : 1, "b" : 2 }
> db.d.find({b: 2, a: 1})
{ "_id" : ObjectId("54c4dfd17e8b0ba11cf1539d"), "a" : 1, "b" : 2 }
```

Test 2 : insert {smthg: {a: 1, b: 2}} and lookup {smthg: {b: 2, a: 1}} -> NOT FOUND

```
> db.d.insert({smthg: {a: 1, b: 2}})
> db.d.find({smthg: {b: 2, a: 1}})
> db.d.find({smthg: {a: 1, b: 2}})
{ "smthg" : { "a" : 1, "b" : 2 } }
```

Thanks for the explanation

Comment: May I ask why you want to save an embeded object in the _id field?

Comment: @joao I use it as a key. for instance : _id: {first_name, last_name} and then I can look up on that. Other reason : mapreduce's key comes in this form

Comment: The document _id is a special unique field that all documents have and should not be messed unless for a good reason. You can solve your problem by adding more fields like you showed on your first example. Also, the map-reduce's results _id has nothing to do with the original documents _id, so no logic in doing so either here.

Comment: @joao 1) I am doing queries on mapreduce results -> I need to query on  _id fields like in this example   2) why does test 1 works ? isn't it supposed to fail because of how mongodb treats ordered dictionaries ? 3) I edited my question and replaced '_id' with 'smthg'. Same result

Comment: check this part of the docs, it answers that question: http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.2/core/read-operations/#subdocuments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll quote the [docs](http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.2/core/read-operations/#subdocuments) directly on this:

> Equality matches within subdocuments select documents if the
>   subdocument matches exactly the specified subdocument, including the
>   field order.

For that purpose, you will be better served using the [dot notation](http://docs.mongodb.org/v2.2/reference/glossary/#term-dot-notation):

```
db.d.find({"smthg.a" : 1, "smthg.b" : 2});
```

Comment: Only to add that **only** in the case of a singular "sub-document" as demonstrated. Where the "sub-document" is a member of an array then the correct notation is `{ "smthng": { "$elemMatch" : { "a": 1, "b": 2 } } }`. But you can only do that for a real "array". Do it for this structure and it will fail because this is not an array.